# Google account autologin in an iphone app

Tags: ios, account, autologin

I am creating an app on iOS that requires a user to login with their google account, but it needs to remember the user for a later time without any user input. For example, if a person quit and reopened the app, it will remember their username and password (or that it has already been verified) and send the user directly into the app. How do I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google uses OAuth for that kind kind functionality. Here's [their guide](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp) on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signInSilently];
```